How to update a global variable while calling request.security in Pine Script
I am trying to count the number of times a condition has occurred in a given timeframe for a list of securities in pine script
//@version=5
indicator("SMA 50 Crossover (N)", overlay = true)

lookback_period = input.int(50, title = "Lookback Period")
thres = input.int(2, title = "Threshold")

sym1 = input.symbol("NSE:DABUR", 'Symbol 1')
sym2 = input.symbol("NSE:RELIANCE", 'Symbol 2')

var sym1counter = 0
var sym2counter = 0

f(x, y) => x + y

method get_ma_rsi(int counter) =>
    rsi = ta.rsi(close, 13)
    ma_rsi = ta.sma(rsi, 13)
    crossover = ta.cross(ma_rsi, rsi)
    
    if crossover and bar_index >= (last_bar_index - lookback_period)
         // Counter is not updating
        // Add the counter if this is true
        [rsi, ma_rsi, f(counter, 1)]
    [rsi, ma_rsi, counter]

[sym1RSI, sym1MARSI, sym1CounterValue] = request.security(sym1, timeframe.period, get_ma_rsi(sym1counter))
[sym2RSI, sym2MARSI, sym2CounterValue] = request.security(sym2, timeframe.period, get_ma_rsi(sym2counter))

sym1counter := sym1CounterValue
sym2counter := sym2CounterValue

var table screener = table.new(position.top_right, 2, 10, bgcolor = color.white, border_color = color.black, border_width = 2,  frame_color = color.black, frame_width = 2)

if barstate.islast
    screener.cell(0,0, str.tostring("Symbol"))
    screener.cell(1,0, str.tostring("Crossovers"))
    screener.cell(0,1, str.tostring(sym1))
    screener.cell(1,1, str.tostring(sym1counter))
    screener.cell(0,2, str.tostring(sym2))
    screener.cell(1,2, str.tostring(sym2CounterValue))
    
// plotchar(counter, title = "Total Crossovers")
plotchar(last_bar_index, "Last Bar Index")
plotchar(last_bar_index - lookback_period, "Lookback period")

This code should basically produce a screener that outputs the count for total number of occurrences in a table but it essentially is showing 0 since the variable is not updating


What is the purpose of [rsi, ma_rsi, f(counter, 1)]? What do you expect to happen in that if branch?

@vitruvius it is to add 1 to counter I have defined the function above

That function will do +1 but where are you using its return value?

@vitruvius I am returning the value and setting it to sym1CounterValue and later assigning the value of sym1CounterValue to sym1counter which I am assuming should be passed to the function again with the incremented value next time.

Exactly where are you using the return value of f() function?
